# Powershell get Logged on Users OU in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains called MY-OU.txt

```
OU=offic-Computers,OU=comp-computers,DC=my,DC=company,DC=com
```

I can get a list of all the computers in that OU:

```
ForEach ($OU in Get-Content "C:\temp\MY-OU.txt")
{
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU -Filter '*' | Select -Exp Name | Out-File -filepath "C:\temp\MY-OU-computers.txt"
}
```

And I can get the current logged on users from the output of the code above:

```
$content = Get-Content C:\temp\MY-OU-computers.txt
$output = foreach ($PC in $content) {Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $PC –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName}
$output | Out-File -filepath "C:\temp\CAD-OU-computers-users.txt"
```

How to combine both parts and get the current logged on users in a specific OU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of outputting the results from `Get-ADComputer` to a file, you can assign them to a variable (`$Computers`), then use that as the input for your next foreach loop:

```
foreach ($OU in Get-Content "C:\temp\MY-OU.txt"){$Computers += Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU -Filter '*' | Select -ExpandProperty Name}

$output = foreach ($PC in $Computers) {Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $PC –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName}
$output | Out-File -filepath "C:\temp\CAD-OU-computers-users.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you @James C.